# OLAP queries in MySql

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, olap-cube

I am trying to implement OLAP queries in MySql.

Here is a relation that I am trying to implement queries on

Cart(product_name,shipper_name,quantity).

I tried running the following query:

```
select product_name,shipper_name, sum(quantity) from Cart group by CUBE(product_name,shipper_name);
```

The above query results in the following error when executed:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CUBE(product_name,shipper_name)' at line 1
```

I am using MySql community version 8.0.

I was expecting a relation in output that performs the group by operation according to the cube operation that we have in SQL.

Comment: Is there a way to implement it by using a combination of operations such as group by union etc.? or can we simply not do it in MySql?

Comment: You need to provide sample data and expected output based on the sample data and we may be able to suggest a solution. Without this, it is anyone's guess what output you are looking for. It may be as simple as using the rollup modifier to rewrite your query.

Comment: Thank You. I was able to implement using roll-up and other operation.